# Qt get QComboBox->currentText within QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qcombobox

I have a QTreeWidget that contains several QComboBoxes. How can I get the current text of a QComboBox that is in the QTreeWidget?

My QTreeWidget looks something like this:

```
ui->sensorTree

parent0
    child0    QComboBox
    child1    QComboBox

parent1
    child0    QComboBox
    child1    QComboBox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the `activated(QString)` signal from the `QComboBox` to a custom slot of your choosing. You can either use a single slot to handle all the activated commands, or multiple slots. My example below uses multiple slots.

```
connect(parent0->child0, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), this, SLOT(child00(QString)));
connect(parent0->child1, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), this, SLOT(child01(QString)));
connect(parent1->child0, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), this, SLOT(child10(QString)));
connect(parent1->child1, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), this, SLOT(child11(QString)));
```

You'll need to repeat the process for each child widget that you make in the `QTreeView`, or use a `QSignalMapper` class to bundle all the signals.